# How to get WP gallery Image Captions?

Tags: php, image, gallery, wordpress

I'm trying to grab gallery images and it's info of a post through a loop. All i'm getting image sources but not the captions. Here is my code

```
<?php
/* The loop */
while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();
    if ( get_post_gallery() ) :
        $gallery = get_post_gallery( get_the_ID(), false );
        /* Loop through all the image and output them one by one */
        foreach( $gallery['src'] AS $src ) {
            ?>

            <img src="<?php echo $src; ?>" class="my-custom-class" alt="Gallery image" />

            <?php
        }
    endif;
endwhile;
?>
```

Using this loop i'm only getting source of the images of the gallery in a post. But I want to grab the image captions too.

Comment: Does `$gallery` contain other fields than 'src'? Could you show the entire structure of `$gallery`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution [on wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/ideas/topic/functions-to-get-an-attachments-caption-title-alt-description):

Stick this in your functions.php:

```
function wp_get_attachment( $attachment_id ) {

    $attachment = get_post( $attachment_id );
    return array(
        'alt' => get_post_meta( $attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true ),
        'caption' => $attachment->post_excerpt,
        'description' => $attachment->post_content,
        'href' => get_permalink( $attachment->ID ),
        'src' => $attachment->guid,
        'title' => $attachment->post_title
    );
}
```

Then you can just pass in the id and grab whatever meta you need like this:

```
attachment_meta = wp_get_attachment(your_attachment_id);
```

And then either loop through the array values or simply reference by the key name of what you want (ie: caption, description, etc.):

```
echo $attachment_meta['caption'];
```

The above would echo the image's caption.

Credit goes to [Luke Mlsna](http://shinraholdings.com/) and [sporkme](http://www.bway.net/) for this.

Answer (score 4):

The [wp_prepare_attachment_for_js](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_prepare_attachment_for_js/) function is really nice for this sort of thing. It returns a TON of info about attachments, everything we'll ever need I think.

Here's the original code snipped replaced with one that makes the caption available. In this case I've placed the caption in the alt tag:

```
<?php
/* The loop */
while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();
    if ( get_post_gallery() ) :
        $gallery = get_post_gallery( get_the_ID(), false );
        /* create an array of IDs from  */
        $gids = explode( ",", $gallery['ids'] );
        /* Loop through all the image and output them one by one */
        foreach ($gids as $id) {
            /* pull all the available attachment data with the new function */
            $attachment = wp_prepare_attachment_for_js($id);
            /* Uncomment the next line to see all the available data in $attachment */
            //var_dump($attachment); 
            /* pick and choose which bits are needed */
            ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $attachment['sizes']['thumbnail']['url']; ?>" class="my-custom-class" alt="<?php echo $attachment['caption']; ?>" />
            <?php
        }
    endif;
endwhile;
?>
```

It's worth noting that this function returns all the available image sizes too, so it might be great when using a combo of [custom image sizes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) and [srcset](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#attr-img-srcset) for responsive image solutions :)

Comment: Great, wish i know about this function earlier

Answer (score 1):

instead passing get_the_ID just pass the whole $post and use code something like this

```
$gallery = get_post_gallery( $post, false );
$gids = explode( ",", $gallery['ids'] );

foreach( $gids as $id ) {
   // here you can use the $id to fetch any details of image like below and many more  
   wp_get_attachment_url( $id );
   wp_get_attachment_metadata( $id );
}
```

You can try to print the value of these functions and use it as per your requirement

Comment: In my testing, this doesn't return the caption. The caption of an attachment is it's 'excerpt' as far as I can see, not in the metadata.

Comment: To return a caption you can use `wp_get_attachment_caption()`